# React Router URL on github pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, react-router, github-pages

I've a live site on Github Pages.

It has URL:

`example.com/frontend-challenges`

it is a app that contain another app like

```
example.com/frontend-challenges/app-1
example.com/frontend-challenges/app-2
example.com/frontend-challenges/app-3
```

I'm using ReactJS/React Router. But whenever I try to access `example.com/frontend-challenges/app-1` without enter `example.com/frontend-challenges` first Github coulnd't find it.

How to overcome this?
URL:

```
https://yoga1234.github.io/frontendmentor-challenges/
```

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages - Use a hash router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for your app is a SPA, and GitHub Pages don't support it.
Here's an instruction to bypass this problem:

https://github.com/rafgraph/spa-github-pages#usage-instructions